# Get img from url in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For sure it's very simple but I just can't do it:

I have this function in jQ:

```
function get_img(user_name){

  var url = "http://example.com/user/" + user_name

  var get_image = $('.user-img[href=' + url +']');

  var img = get_image.find('img').attr('src')
}
```

But what I get is:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .user-img[href=http://example.com/user/userx]

with highlighted last - " ] " . So as I think there is problem with quotes.

How Can I get img from URL in this way.

Comment: You need quotes around the `href` value. Just hardcode double quotes into your string before and after the `url` concatenation`.

Comment: "href=http://example.com/user/userx]" - syntax error ... when I set quotes for value I do not get it value but just string.

Comment: `$('.user-img[href="' + url +'"]');`

Comment: ok thanks ... exackly duplicated topic. Thanks